# outlook 2010 only cache last X months

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using outlook 2010 in cached mode for better performance, however I now have 50G of local cache. Most of that I am not interested in, so I was wondering if and how I can cache only the last X months. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this per folder in Outlook 2010.

1. Right click the folder (eg; Inbox), and go to Properties
2. Go to the Synchronization tab
3. Click the Filter button
4. Create an Advanced filter rule based on the Received field. Set the filter condition to be `on or after` and the value to be `x months ago` (replace x!)

There is a [good article](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/reduce-ost-file-size-with-synchronization-filters) on msoutlook.info that can provide further information.

Outlook 2013 has a [built in feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2733062) where you can select the cache time of an Exchange account, but this seems to be the only way to do it for Outlook 2010.

There also might be a setting that your Exchange administrator can modify, but I'm not aware of it.